# Rename plone site

Tags: plone

In the past I've heard that it can be dangerous to rename the Plone site object(change it's id).

Is renaming dangerous? What are the potential issues when renaming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the references (from http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/Renaming-the-Plone-object-via-ZMI-td4428462.html):

> I am trying to rename the Plone object via the Zope Management Interface, however as a side effect, all references I have on "reference_catalog" are lost, including LinguaPlone translations, related content and the path criteria from collections.
>
> I am using Plone 3.1.7, and you can reproduce the problem by creating a vanilla Plone object, add some Documents with related content pointing to each other, add a Folder and Collection, and add a path criterion to the collection, pointing to that folder. Check "reference_catalog". After that, rename the portal object and "reference_catalog" will be empty.
>
> Is there any sollution for this problem?"

Which was answered with:

> You need to update your catalog, since the plone object's id is the
> first element of the path of all your content.
> http://plone.org/documentation/error/portal-content-has-gone-missing/

In the thread there are some links to scripts to avoid losing references.

Comment: I mean the problem is in the references.

Comment: ops, edited and removed an unnecessary part about reindexing which should be quite obvious.

Comment: np, recovered that for you, and added a little formatting and clarifications.

Answer (score 3):

Any reference to an object that is stored as a path will be a problem. As Yuri's answer points out, that includes the paths in catalogs. That's a relatively easy one to deal with, by doing a full rebuild of the catalog. There are other issues that may be harder to find, such as paths within collection criteria and portlet data.